# Using Timer To Pause Program Execution

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, timer

I want to pause the execution of a Swing Program for a specified amount of time. Naturally the first thing that I used was Thread.sleep(100) (since, I am a noob). Then I got to know that my program is not thread safe so I decided to use Timer with some suggestions from fellow programmers. The problem is I am unable to get any sources from where I can learn how to delay the thread, using Timer. Most of them use Timer for delaying execution. Please help me solve this problem. I have provided a compileable code snippet below.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MatrixBoard_swing extends JFrame{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            MatrixBoard_swing b = new MatrixBoard_swing();      
          }
       });
    }

    MatrixBoard_swing(){
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.setVisible(true);
        while(rad < 200){
            repaint();
            rad++;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }

    int rad = 10;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(400-rad, 400-rad, rad, rad); 
    }

}
```

EDIT: My trial for a Timer implementation(please tell me if it is wrong):

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class MatrixBoard_swing extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
            MatrixBoard_swing b = new MatrixBoard_swing();      
          }
       });
    }

    MatrixBoard_swing(){
        this.setSize(640, 480);
        this.setVisible(true);
        timer = new Timer(100, this);
        timer.start();
    }

    int rad = 10;

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawOval(400-rad, 400-rad, rad, rad); 
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        repaint();
        rad++;
        if(rad >= 200){
            timer.stop();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're still calling `Thread.sleep(...)` on the Swing event thread. I thought that we had this ironed out in your [previous similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21800147/repaint-is-not-functioning-properly-as-required). What gives?

Comment: *"Using Timer To Pause Program Execution"*  Pause what exactly, the GUI rendering?  The GUI doing some long running operation?  Allowing user input?  Note that `while(rad < 200){ ... Thread.sleep(100);` indicates a common, classic mistake with rendering animation in a GUI.

Comment: I am unable to understand how to use the Timer. You had advised me to provide a simple, compileable code. So I posted it here.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: he's already been told all of this.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: Yes, I want to pause the GUI rendering. I know what you are saying. I just want an example as to how.

Comment: We want to see your attempt to use a Swing Timer, not your attempt to use something that you should already know shouldn't be used. Else, how can we know what you might be doing wrong? How will we know what you may be misunderstanding?

Comment: [My Timer pause execution example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21869462/522444). Now let's see yours.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: My problem is that I have the above code that I want to convert to one that uses Timer. I just don't see how I must do it. So if you can provide me a working example, I will be able to use it in my project. I apologise if it is rong.

Comment: Again, what bugs me is that you haven't even shown us an attempt to use Timer. Why not even try? Why ask us to write this for you without at least showing an attempt. Yes, this is wrong -- please fix it.

Comment: *"EDIT: I will soon be posting an attempt to try out the Timer."*  +1

Comment: Thanks a lot Andrew and Hovercraft for encouraging me to try it myself. Please can you check if the method is correct? And sorry for being a complete noob.

Comment: And what's wrong with your attempt then?

Comment: @MadProgrammer: The problem got solved (I solved it myself with a bit of a push from Andrew and Hovercraft). Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So instead of...

```
while(rad < 200){
    repaint();
    rad++;
    try {
        Thread.sleep(100);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

You simply need to turn the logic around a little...

```
Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        rad++;
        if (rad < 200) {
            repaint();
        } else {
            ((Timer)evt.getSource()).stop();
        }
    }
});
timer.start();
```

Basically, the `Timer` will act as the `Thread.sleep()`, but in a nice way that doesn't break the UI, but will allow you to inject a delay between execution.  Each time it executes, you need to increment your value, test for the "stop" condition and update otherwise...

Take a look at [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and the other 3, 800 questions on the subject on SO...